# How to use Scanner Input as a filename using Formatter class

Tags: java

I am new at coding and have a question how to fix this code to actually use the User Input as the new name for the created file.
As you see, I want the String "Filename" to be used in the Formatter
(e.g. The Input is "Example.txt" this should be used in the Constructor of the Formatter as the Filename)

```
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FileCreator {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Scanner Question1=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What should be your file's name?");
        String Filename=Question1.nextLine();
        try {
            Formatter f=new Formatter("xxPath\\Filename");          
            f.format("%s %s","file","created");
            System.out.println("Succes");               
            f.close();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }       
    }}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Use the variable and not a fixed string:

```
Formatter f=new Formatter("xxPath\\"+Filename);
```

BTW: Learning about java naming convention. Variable names should start with a lower case charachter.

Comment: thanks for your quick response, I changed it but i get the Error "String literal is not properly closed by double quotes". how's that, if I try to use the variable? 

 String filename=Question1.nextLine();
        try {
         Formatter f=new Formatter("D:\\Code\\"+filename");

Comment: @LeonJasper remove the double quotes here: `");`